# Codename One - Button to put in background an app

Tags: codenameone

Which actionListener can I add to a button to put the app in the background?

Moreover, can I put an app in background automatically at the end of the `start()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Display.getInstance().minimizeApplication()` to minimize the app. I'm not sure if this will behave properly in the end of the `start()` method as we assume an app is launched for the purpose of showing a UI.

Comment: In my case it works at the end of the `start()` method, however I agree that starting a minimized app is a uncommon use case.